# Will direct access to a webdav-mounted file cause problems?

Tags: webdav

I'm thinking about configuring the remind calendar program so that I can use the same .reminders file from my Ubuntu box at home and from my Windows box at work.  What I'm going to try to do is to make the directory on my home machine that contains the file externally visible through webdav on Apache.  (Security doesn't really concern me, because my home firewall only forwards ssh, to hit port 80 my my home box, you need to use ssh tunneling.)

Now my understanding is that webdav was designed to arbitrate simultaneous access attempts.  My question is whether this is compatible with direct file access from the host machine.  That is, I understand that if I have two or more remote webdav clients trying to edit the same file, the webdav protocol is supposed to provide locking, so that only one client can have access, and hence the file will not be corrupted.

My question is whether these protections will also protect against local edits going through the filesystem, rather than through webdav.  Should I mount the webdav directory, on the host machine, and direct all local edits through the webdav mount?  Or is this unnecessary?

(In this case, with only me accessing the file, it's exceedingly unlikely that I'd get simultaneous edits, but I like to understand how systems are supposed to work ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not accessing the files under the WebDAV protocol, you're not honoring locks set via LOCK and UNLOCK methods and therefore will open to potential to overwrite changes made by another client. This situation is described in the WebDAV RFC here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-7.2